# 中(なか) vs 中(ちゅう)

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

Some of you already gave good answers to the question in the title a while back, but I found some computer-generated pronunciations that confuse me. Are the following sentences' readings correct? Thank you in advance!

> お話し中すみませんが。
>   お はなし ちゅう すみません が。
>   May I interrupt you for a moment?
>
> そこら中の筋肉が痛む。
>   そこらじゅう の きんにく が いたむ。
>   I ache all over.
>
> そのパーティーは真夜中に終わった。
>   その パーティー は まよなか に おわった。✓
>   The party came to an end at midnight.
>
> その晩と次の日とその夜中ずっと地下室で過ごしたのよ。
>   その ばん と つぎ の ひ と その よなか ずっと ちかしつ で すごした の よ。✓
>   We spent all of that night, the next day, and the next night in the cellar.
>
> もう夜中を過ぎた。
>   もう よなか を すぎた。✓
>   It's midnight already.
>
> 彼はヨーロッパ中を旅行した。
>   かれはヨーロッパじゅうをりょこうした。✓
>   He traveled all over Europe.
>
> 一日中
>   いちにちじゅう
>   all day long
>
> 一日中歩き回って大変疲れた。
>   いちにちじゅう あるきまわって たいへん つかれた。
>   I am dead tired from walking around all day.
>
> 僕らは夜中の２時まで話していた。
>   ぼくら は よなか の にじ まで はなしていた。✓
>   We talked until two in the morning.
>
> 夜中に申し訳ありません。
>   やちゅう に もうしわけ ありません。
>   I'm sorry to bother you at night.
>
> 容器を見ずに中身を見よ。
>   ようき を みず に なかみ を みよ。
>   Do not look upon the vessel but upon that which it contains.
>
> 彼はほとんど真夜中に家に帰った。
>   かれ は ほとんど まよなか に いえ に かえった。✓
>   He came home at almost midnight.
>
> 彼は息子を捜して町中を歩き回った。
>   かれ は むすこ を さがして まちなか を あるきまわった。
>   He walked the streets looking for his son.
>
> 彼は私に真夜中に電話してきた。
>   かれ は わたし に まよなか に でんわ して きた。✓
>   He rang me up at midnight.
>
> 私は夜中過ぎまで夫を待った。
>   わたし は よなかすぎ まで おっと を まった。✓
>   I waited for my husband until after midnight.
>
> 私は夜中過ぎまで夫を待った。
>   わたし は やちゅう すぎ まで おっと を まった。
>   I waited for my husband till after midnight.
>
> 背丈は中くらいです。
>   せたけ は ちゅうくらい です。
>   He is of medium height.
>
> 電話は話し中だ。
>   でんわ は はなし ちゅう だ。
>   The line is busy.

Comment: Partly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5371/9831

Answer (score 3):

These are almost perfect, but I think 夜中 in その夜中ずっと地下室で過ごした should be read よるじゅう ("all over the night"), and 夜中過ぎ in 私は夜中過ぎまで夫を待った should be read よなかすぎ ("past midnight"). It's probably better to read 町中 in 息子を捜して町中を歩き回った as まちじゅう ("all over the town") if there is no specific context.

Sometimes the same kanji word can have more than one reading with different meanings/register.

- 町中

  - **まちなか**: (=町の中) in the town, on the street
  - **まちじゅう**: (=町の全体) all over the town
    (In general, `place name + じゅう` means "all over ～")
- 夜中

  - **よなか**: (=深夜) late at night, midnight
    (真夜中 is always まよなか)
  - **よるじゅう**: (=夜の全体) all over the night
  - **やちゅう**: (=夜の間) during the night
    (This is a fairly uncommon and highly stiff word choice)

Comment: Thank you! Without help such as yours, self-directed Japanese learning is challenging, since sites such as https://j-talk.com/convert do not always provide completely reliable pronunciations of the kanji in example sentences. :D