# Kanji after gairaigo pronunciation

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, loanwords

For instance, in "アカウントにサインイン中です。" How is "中" pronounced?

At a purely mental level, I've always maintained the idea that how you read is up to you, which seems to be backed by stylistic differences in furigana usage. (Just... as an example.) However, there does come a time, even in the hermit and/or quiet person's life when one will need to speak and be understood!

Sorry for the monologue. Anyway, my educated guess is that it is pronounced なか, although my brain seems to lean more towards じゅう when not reading aloud.
Bonus points (Not sure how they would be awarded.) if you can provide counter-examples-- given they exist!

Comment: It's pronounced ちゅう.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5371/9831

Comment: Trying to understand what you mean by "how you read is up to you"... Generally speaking there is going to be only one way to read a sentence that the vast majority of natives would agree is correct. There are exceptions where some reading variations are perfectly interchangeable, but often choosing a different reading changes the meaning or register, or results in it being unnatural or even ungrammatical.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't see the other question!!